# Select Different Columns in same Row

Tags: vba, select

```
Sub Change_Format()
    Dim Row1 as Integer
    Row1 = 4
    Do While Cells(Row1, 2) <> ""
        If Cells(Row1, 2).ColorIndex = 255 Or Cells(Row1, 2).ColorIndex = 5287936 Then
            Range.(Cells(Row1, 5), Cells(Row1, 6),Cells(Row1, 7)).Select
            Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

I'm having trouble to select the columns 5, 6 and 7 in the row , I searched everywhere so I think there is no way of doing it, u guys are my last hope if u know how please tell me.

```
Sub Change_Format()

Dim Row1 As Integer
Row1 = 4

Do While Cells(Row1, 2) <> ""
    If Cells(Row1, 1) = "OK" Then
        Cells(Row1, 5).Resize(, 3).Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
    End If
    Row1 = Row1 + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Hi everyone, this is the code I'm using now and works just fine, I'm just curious about one thing, what if I want to select jumping the columns for example same Row and columns 4, 6 and 8 .select

Sorry to bother again and thanks for helping.

Comment: You're looking for `.Resize` and perhaps `.Offset` - `.Resize(,3)`

Comment: I suppose that you want to delete the cells based on conditional formatting. Unfortunately, the `ColorIndex` would be `0`, although you may see some color, because it comes from conditional formatting. The best way is to simulate the condition of the conditional formatting and to delete based on it.

Comment: Vityata, I'm actually using the colour of a differente cell as a condition not the cell with the conditional formatting. But it didn't work anyways, so I changed my If and now everything is F***ING AWESOME!!!!! Thanks for ur support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you likely just want `.Resize`

```
Sub Change_Format()
    Dim Row1 As Integer
    Row1 = 4
    Do While Cells(Row1, 2) <> ""
        If Cells(Row1, 2).ColorIndex = 255 Or Cells(Row1, 2).ColorIndex = 5287936 Then
            Cells(Row1, 5).Resize(,3).Select 'Select 3 columns to the right
            Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Here's an example of a simple subroutine that selects 3 columns to the right of a row/column:

```
Sub Select3Columns(TheRow As Long, TheColumn As Variant)
Cells(TheRow, TheColumn).Resize(, 3).Select
End Sub
```

The result of `Select3Columns 5,"A"`:

[image: Results]